# Передача данных через socket python сервер-сервер

Tags: python, сокет, клиент-сервер

Код сервера:

```
import socket
# слушаем и отправляем данные
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print(host)
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('adr：', addr)
    c.send(b'test')
    c.close()
```

Клиент:

```
# получаем данные
import socket
s_get = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 10000
s_get.connect((host, port))
print(s_get.recv(1024).decode())
```

Если я запускаю каждый отдельно, то сообщение отправляется и действительно работает клиент-сервер.

А как мне сделать сервер-сервер, чтобы два сервера между собой общались и постоянно передавали друг другу информацию?

Comment: Никак, сервер-сервер не бывает такого. На обоих сторонах должна быть клиентская часть.

Comment: @0xdb, возьми даже тот же игровой сервер, в нем участвует `login-server` и `game-server` и `client`, при это `login<>server` общаются между собой на этапе входа в мир, при этом на клиенте нужно шифровать пакеты, а при взаимодействии `login<>game` - этого делать не нужно.

Comment: @And Совершенно верно, как сервер и клиент.

Comment: в чём вопрос? Если хотите принимать соединения, то используйте код сервера, если хотите к существующему серверу подключиться, то используйте код клиента. Ничто не мешает внутри одного процесса, как код клиента  так и сервера выполнять (threads, async IO). Способы связи могут быть самыми разнообразными в зависимости от задачи (можно посмотреть на многочисленные примеры в [ZeroMQ документации](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), которые являются крошечной долей того что может встречаться).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо смотреть в строну архитектуры сетевого взаимодействия под названием «децентрализованная сеть», `Peer to peer`, где все участники сети потонцеальные и сервера и клиенты, пример такой сети это `BitTorrent`, а пример реализации [вот](https://m.habr.com/post/304150). Так-же в сети есть куча готовых вариантов, такие как [эти](https://github.com/adamgillfillan/p2p). Советую совместно с этим типом сетей, изучать параллельную модель выполнения в программных приложениях.

Comment: Вы угадали, надо именно p2p, для взаимодействия компьютеров между собой и достижения консенсуса. По вашей ссылке, p2p модуль не обновлялся больше 4 лет. Как думаете, что из этого лучше:
1) 
http://v0-6.p2p.today/python/tutorial/mesh.html   2)
https://github.com/ethereum/pydevp2p   3)
https://github.com/namuyan/p2p-python

Comment: Информации не бывает много. Попробуйте все, проверьте на нагружаемость, потом уже.

Answer (score 0):

Сервер-сервер взаимодействие - это выполнение одновременно двух функций каждым участником: функций клиента (подключение к другим серверам) и сервера (прием подключений от других серверов). Вообще, если говорить про кластер,  то обычно разделяют эти общения по разным портам. Серверы между собой общаются по одному, а реальных клиентов обслуживают по другому.